# Page number within diamond box

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I want to insert diamond around page numbers of my thesis file. I am using thesis documentclass. The pages numbers appear on top right corner.

Comment: Where did you get that document class?

Comment: I don't remember but few months ago I downloaded the thesis template from internet and the documentclass is Thesis. By the way, if you google it you can find several links to download Thesis class.

Comment: So it will be hard to help you. We need to read your code exactly as it is. Or at least, tell us if you are inserting header using `fancyhdr` for example.

Comment: \fancyhead{}  % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage}  % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{}  % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy}  % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

Comment: This is all what I can search about headers from my code

Comment: So, replace `\rhead{\thepage}` by `\rhead{$\diamond$ \thepage}`.

Comment: Thanks but this just include diamond symbol beside page number. Instead I want page number within the diamond shape!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18393/discussion-between-mani-and-sigur).

Answer (score 1):

With `tikz` and `shapes.geometric` library

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{thesis}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields 
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields

\newcommand{\diam}[1]{\tikz\draw (0,0)node[shape aspect=1,diamond,draw,,inner sep=2pt]{#1};}

\rhead{\diam{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter one}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{section one}
\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

The result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it, but it didn't work. Is there any typo in defining new command? I can see two consecutive commas , after draw and before inner